# Apache httpd - redirect non-www & http to https://www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, centos, virtualhost

I am looking to direct all traffic to https://www.domain.co.uk. So whenever http://www.domain.co.uk, http://domain.co.uk or even https://domain.co.uk is requested it gets redirected to https://www.domain.co.uk.

I have had difficulties trying to achieve this using Virtual Hosts in httpd.conf. I have tried the following (and many other variations.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.co.uk
    ServerAlias domain.co.uk
    Redirect / https://www.domain.co.uk     
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin system@domain.co.uk
        ServerName  domain.co.uk
        ServerAlias www.domain.co.uk
        DirectoryIndex index.html
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.co.uk
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/www.domain.co.uk.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/www.domain.co.uk.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/ssl/www.domain.co.uk-geotrust.crt
        <Directory /var/www/html/domain.co.uk>
            Options FollowSymLinks 
            AllowOverride all
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.co.uk
        ServerName domain.co.uk
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin system@domain.co.uk
        ServerName  domain.co.uk
        ServerAlias *.domain.co.uk

        <Directory /var/www/html/domain.co.uk>
            Options FollowSymLinks 
            AllowOverride all
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain.co.uk
</VirtualHost>
```

Using the above set up when I go to http://domain.co.uk I get a 403 Forbidden response. Also, when visiting https://domain.co.uk, it doesn't get redirected and I therefore get a Privacy Error on Chrome.

If you could help me achieve my goal, I would be very grateful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create this rule in `/var/www/html/domain.co.uk/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```